# Check if $F_1(k,x) = F(k,x) \oplus x$ is pseudorandom

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function, computational-complexity-theory

Let F be a pseudorandom function. Check if if $F_1(k,x) = F(k,x) \oplus x$ is pseudorandom( $\oplus$ is bitwise XOR).

I found this question in a book. I am not sure how to proceed :

$F_1(k,x) = F(k,x) \oplus x \implies F(k,x) \oplus F_1(k, x) = x$

Now do we assume that we know $F(k,x), F_1(k,x)$ ? **Because if we do I found x, by xoring these.**
In general, is there a methodology for proving a function non  pseudorandom ?
I have the definition of pseudorandomness of course, but it does not seem really practical.

Comment: In the question, you are interacting with $F_1$ thought you can assume you know the implementation of both. But you *don't know* both $F(k,x)$ and $F_1(k,x)$, you only get $F_1(k,x)$ for a $x$ you choose. A strategy to prove the negative is to exhibit an example of $F$ such that $F_1$ is distinguishable from a random function. To prove the positive, show that if one can break $F_1$, then it can also break $F$, which contradicts the starting assumption that F is secure.

Comment: @MarcIlunga If I know x then I can  compute F(k, x) for all possible k and see which gives me F1(k,x) = F(k, x) xor x . That is $O(2^n)$ when I know that k has n bits.

Comment: @MarcIlunga As for what you said I am not sure I get it : when you say to prove the negative you mean to prove that F1 is not pseudorandom? How can I find an example F, where F1 is distinguishable from a random function?

Comment: A brute force attack is always possible for most applied schemes, but for a reasonable key space (like 128 bits), this is practically impossible. A general trick to find a counter-example is to start with an $F$ that is secure and "sabotage" it carefully such that the sabotage version remains secure but when used inside $F_1$, $F_1$ becomes insecure.

Comment: @MarcIlunga Isn't knowing $x$ reveals both $F(k,x)$ and $F_1(k,x)$ if one can choose $x$. tonythestark it is easy with contrapositive. Assume that $F_1$ is not pseudo-random then conclude that $F$ is also not a pseudo-random.

Comment: @kelalaka, that is correct, we can recover $F(k,x)$. For some reason, I had something else in mind while writing this (Sorry @tonythestark)... But yeah, I agree with the proof strategy that I also outlined in the first comment, but didn't want to spoil the result.

Comment: tonythestark, you can write your answer...